# How do I get the Query Timing with sqlcmd?

Tags: linux, client, benchmark, native-client, sql-server-2017

Running SQL Server 2017, using the interactive [REPL client `sqlcmd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) how do I get the time for Query Execution?

You can [sp_BlitzErik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/sp-blitzerik) showing this in [his answer here,](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174093/2639)

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
  CPU time = 1859 ms,  elapsed time = 321 ms.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for are the `SET STATISTICS` commands:

- [`SET STATISTICS TIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql)
- [`SET STATISTICS IO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql)

They work for me using sqlcmd on windows:

[image: sqlcmd windows]

Comment: Cool this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Joe's answer but want to mention about a built in switch which give you few more data point. You can do it with [`-p` switch.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

> Prints performance statistics for every result set. The following is
>   an example of the format for performance statistics:
>
> Where:
>
> ```
> x = Number of transactions that are processed by SQL Server .
> t1 = Total time for all transactions.
> t2 = Average time for a single transaction.
> t3 = Average number of transactions per second.
> ```
>
> All times are in milliseconds.
>
> If the optional parameter 1 is specified, the output format of the
>   statistics is in colon-separated format that can be imported easily
>   into a spreadsheet or processed by a script.  If the optional
>   parameter is any value other than 1, an error is generated and sqlcmd
>   exits.

With optional 1 with `p` switch.[image]

By default this will add a footer to the query that looks like this,

```
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
1 xact[s]:
Clock Time (ms.): total         1  avg   1.0 (1000.0 xacts per sec.)
```

Comment: I believe this would likely be the clock time for the client which includes network transit and the like. But it's a good answer. ;)