# SQL Server returns "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, datatypes, sql-server-2017

When I run this command with `SUM()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Records], SUM(t.Amount) AS [Total]
FROM   dbo.t1 AS t
WHERE  t.Id > 0
       AND t.Id < 101;
```

I'm getting,

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Any idea on what is the cause of it?

I'm just following the instructions in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174093/2639).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For values larger than the `INT` max (2,147,483,647), you'll want to use [COUNT_BIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-big-transact-sql)(*).

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Records], SUM(t.Amount) AS [Total]
FROM   dbo.t1 AS t
WHERE  t.Id > 0
       AND t.Id < 101;
```

If it's happening in the `SUM`, you need to convert `Amount` to a `BIGINT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Records], SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, t.Amount)) AS [Total]
FROM   dbo.t1 AS t
WHERE  t.Id > 0
       AND t.Id < 101;
```

Answer (score 11):

This issue is caused by `SUM()` function

you have to CAST `t.Amount` as `BIGINT`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Records], SUM(CAST(t.Amount AS BIGINT)) AS [Total]
FROM   dbo.t1 AS t
WHERE  t.Id > 0
       AND t.Id < 101;
```

**Reference**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289310/how-to-prevent-arithmetic-overflow-error-when-using-sum-on-int-column